# old interior door knob can't turn

Tags: doors

We have a closet door knob that it very hard to turn.

I have tried taking it apart and using WD-40 but that is only good for about 3 weeks then it becomes hard again.

Is there other way I can get this to turn better?

Would a Carb and Choke Cleaner be better and sould it be the Aerosol Can type of the Chem Dip Parts Cleaner?

[image: door knob]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WD-40 is not a lubricant which is why it's only lasting a short time.

Use something to clean it out, carb and choke cleaner is reasonable and follow that with some compressed air.

Then apply some graphite-based lock lube to the moving parts.  These are also often called "dry" lube and they don't hold dust like oil-based lubes can.

Once it all moves freely with the new lube, you should be good to go.

Comment: had pretty much my exact thought. I completely agree with why WD-40 is lasting as a "lube" and how to address cleaning and lubing it.